# Java JOGL se queda en gris

Tags: java, jogl

He probado un programa de Java JOGL, al compilarlo no da ningún error y las librerías están correctamente instaladas, sin embargo, aunque no da ningún error, crea la ventana y el titulo correctamente pero solo muestra el fondo (un simple color rojo) durante un segundo y posteriormente se queda en gris. Ocasionalmente (no siempre) al maximizar la venta aparece correctamente y permanece el fondo, otras veces vuelve a desaparecer.

He buscado en Google y he encontrado que podría deberse a una incompatibilidad con el antialising de la tarjeta gráfica y que desactivandolo se solucionaba. Después de desactivarlo el problema persiste.

Utilizo netbeans 20 con JDK 11 y una tarjeta gráfica nvidia RTX3060Ti.

Aquí dejo el código.

```
package code;

import javax.swing.*;

import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL4.*;

import com.jogamp.opengl.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;


public class Code extends JFrame implements GLEventListener
{
    /**
     * Atrivutos privados
     */
    private final int WIDTH = 600;
    private final int HEIGHT = 400;
    
    private GLCanvas myCanvas;
    
    
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Code()
    {
        setTitle("Window with Background Red");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setLocation(400, 50);
        
        myCanvas = new GLCanvas();
        myCanvas.addGLEventListener(this);
        
        this.add(myCanvas);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    /**
     * Métodos públicos
     */
    
    /** @param drawable */
    @Override public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
    {
        GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
        
        gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
    
    @Override public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {}
    @Override public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {}
    @Override public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {}
    
    
    /**
     * static Main
     * @param args 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Code();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras darle muchas vueltas he descartado que el problema sea la incompatibilidad con la tarjeta gráfica, ya que este problema no es de JOGL si no de las bibliotecas awt y swing; he realizado pruebas con ambas y funcionan correctamente.

Sólo quedaba entonces que fuera problema del propio JOGL, leyendo diferente documentación he encontrado que en tarjetas gráficas potentes como puede ser una rtx en una maquina windows, puede precisar pasar una opción por línea de comandos deshabilitando el uso de aceleración Direct3D así:

-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false

Con esto funciona correctamente.